# Filtering results from Spotipy API call

Tags: python, spotipy

I am writing a program which gets the currently playing song from my spotify account and prints it. This works fine however I am wondering how to filter the result so that only the artist name or album name is printed.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.oauth2 as oauth2

CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID"
CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET"
scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'
username = "username"
redirect_uri = "redirect_uri"

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,
                            scope,
                            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                            redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

current_track = spotify.current_user_playing_track()

if current_track == None:
    print("No current track")
else:
    print(current_track)
```

And this is the result:

```
{'timestamp': 1568386316955, 'context': {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh', 'type': 'album', 'uri': 'spotify:album:2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh'}, 'progress_ms': 38154, 'item': {'album': {'album_type': 'album', 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi', 'id': '7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi', 'name': 'Stevie Wonder', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA'], 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh', 'id': '2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh', 'images': [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/c68e9e8dc926a35a8cd3b787b4886e5918be8e20', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/7479462358bbb61069732c0560a0873f1b2e7dad', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/7670385f653e3ee03d969afde1fd80a0a067613f', 'width': 64}], 'name': 'Hotter Than July', 'release_date': '1980-09-29', 'release_date_precision': 'day', 'total_tracks': 10, 'type': 'album', 'uri': 'spotify:album:2tO3rrZ6q3OjHJMGVo13dh'}, 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi', 'id': '7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi', 'name': 'Stevie Wonder', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:7guDJrEfX3qb6FEbdPA5qi'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA'], 'disc_number': 1, 'duration_ms': 307933, 'explicit': False, 'external_ids': {'isrc': 'USUMG9900475'}, 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/5EAgXGJ8Kw5QAfhQkZXYqT'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/5EAgXGJ8Kw5QAfhQkZXYqT', 'id': '5EAgXGJ8Kw5QAfhQkZXYqT', 'is_local': False, 'name': "Master Blaster (Jammin')", 'popularity': 61, 'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/391e6b08051b98ba7d9608833331b5cd837a201e?cid=b234dc53e9ee48c5b1e30906c13a8252', 'track_number': 6, 'type': 'track', 'uri': 'spotify:track:5EAgXGJ8Kw5QAfhQkZXYqT'}, 'currently_playing_type': 'track', 'actions': {'disallows': {'resuming': True}}, 'is_playing': True}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what it prints now?

Comment: I've edited the post to contain the output.

Comment: You will have to find the specific parts you want from the nested dictionaries and lists in `current_track`.  For example to get "Stevie Wonder" use: `print(current_track['item']['album']['artists'][0]['name'])`.  I would spend some time learning how to navigate this object as being able to use nested dictionaries will help a lot using python in the future!